# WPF - Increase scrollbar width of existing style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm currently using MahApps.Metro to style my WPF controls. When I add a ScrollViewer to components the MahApps.Metro style is used, but while I like the style, the width of the scrollbar (vertical) isn't suitable for my needs. Could someone suggest a way to increase the width of an existing style (from a library, although source is available on github)?

I've tried using:

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollBar"><Setter Property="Width" Value="50"/></Style>
```

but it reverts the MahApps.Metro style back to the WPF default, but with thicker scrollbars. After this, I tried using:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">100</sys:Double>
```

but it seemed to have no visual effect.

- [MahApps.Metro Website](http://mahapps.com/)
- [MahApps.Metro Github](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/tree/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like their `ScrollBar` style overrides the width and height with different resource keys:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Orientation"
             Value="Horizontal">
        <Setter Property="Height"
                Value="{DynamicResource MetroScrollBarHeight}" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="Orientation"
             Value="Vertical">
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="{DynamicResource MetroScrollBarWidth}" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Try dropping in a resource override like you did before, but use their custom resource key instead:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="MetroScrollBarWidth">100</sys:Double>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was after. I guess it's simple when you know where to look. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: With version MahApps.Metro 2.0 (currently in alpha). `MetroScrollBarWidth` has changed to `MahApps.Sizes.ScrollBar.Width`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Mike Strobel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26553114/492), and in the best copy-paste traditions, here is how I got it to work ...

```xml
<ScrollViewer
    Name="scrlMain"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    CanContentScroll="True"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
        <system:Double  x:Key="MetroScrollBarWidth">20</system:Double>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
```